# Целесообразность использования std i/o streams из стандратной библиотеки

Tags: c++, c++11

В стандартной библиотеке есть часть для работы с вводом\выводом: `std iostreams`. Хотелось бы понять, насколько целесообразно ее использования после появления C++11 ?

Источники по использованию STD i\o streams:

1. Лекция на Yandex-events: [Ещё раз о std::iostreams](https://events.yandex.ru/lib/talks/3309/)
2. Статья на habrahabr.ru: [Насколько медленны iostreams?](https://habrahabr.ru/post/246257/)

P.S.:

Предвидя некоторые вопросы и фразы хочу сказать, что мне уже говорили, что оно не бросает исключений, на этот случай есть вызов метода `stream.exceptions(std::ios::failbit | std::ios::badbit | std::ios::eofbit)`. Также говорили, что слишком медленна и на это тоже есть решение `stream.sync_with_stdio(false)`.

Comment: В качестве альтернативы вы видите printf()/scanf()?

Comment: А что в C++11 появилось такого, чем можно заменить потоки?...

Comment: Ну к примеру `std::ios::failure` уже не от `std::exception`, а от `std::system_error`. Есть и др. изменения. Вопрос как раз и задан с целью узнать мнение более опытных товарищей

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Т.к. в C++ 11 не появилось никаких альтернативных средств по вводу/выводу, то и вопрос смысла не имеет. Если встроенные средства удовлетворяли до появления C++ 11, то они продолжат удовлетворять и после его выхода. Если нет, тогда нет.

Answer (score 0):

По поводу эффективности - набросал простенький тест, приведен ниже. Результат на моей машине в Windows 7 с VC++ 2015 - при выводе в консоль

```
cout sync : 3204554
cout async: 3225070
stdout    : 1153035
```

при перенаправлении в файл

```
cout sync : 4695
cout async: 4818
stdout    : 2334
```

Так что, конечно, `stdout` получается побыстрее, но как минимум небезопаснее... Что касается `sync_with_stdio(false)` - похоже, миф :)

Исходник:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdio>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    const int Count = 10000;
    vector<int> data;
    for(int i = 0; i < Count; ++i) data.push_back(rand());

    auto start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for(auto i: data)
    {
        printf("%d ",i);
    }
    auto stop = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    cout << endl;
    auto printf_time = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(stop-start).count();

    start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for(auto i: data)
    {
        cout << i << " ";
    }
    stop = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    cout << endl;
    auto iostream_sync_time = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(stop-start).count();

    cout.sync_with_stdio(false);

    start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for(auto i: data)
    {
        cout << i << " ";
    }
    stop = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    cout << endl;
    auto iostream_async_time = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(stop-start).count();

    cout << "cout sync : " << iostream_sync_time << endl;
    cout << "cout async: " << iostream_async_time << endl;
    cout << "stdout    : " << printf_time << endl;


}
```

И все же - никак не могу понять, почему ТС увязывает вопрос именно с C++11. Ведь никаких изменений в этой области не было.

Comment: 'sync_with_stdio(false)' посмотрел в статье на habr-е: https://habrahabr.ru/post/246257/

Comment: @sys_dev Охотно поверю, что в какой-то реализации C++ и какой-то операционке это и подействует, но у себя - особой разницы не вижу...

Comment: А почему вы меряете не в CPU time ?

Comment: Думаю, роли не играет. Кстати, промерьте и расскажите результаты - особенно если у вас другая среда, интересно посмотреть. Как и на исследования `cin`. Готовую программу, буде дадите текст, могу и у себя посмотреть, а самому сочинять - времени жалко...

Comment: `sync_with_stdio(false)` нужно вызывать до вывода, любого. Т.е. в самом начале, поэтому два теста sync&async не имеют смысла. Но это общую картину не изменит, конечно. Использование буфера всегда даст результат медленнее, чем прямая запись.

Comment: кроме `sync_with_stdio(false)` добавьте ещё `cin.tie(0)` эта связка значительно ускоряет cin/cout (_обычно_ они работают быстрее scanf/printf после этого). Если нужно ещё быстрее пишут свой примитивный парсер.

Comment: @pavel: Спасибо! Только что узнал об этом, но не от Вас, а в докладе : https://events.yandex.ru/lib/talks/3309/ . Там Д.Прокопцев рекомендует сделать `std::cin.tie(nullptr)`. Пожалуй добавлю это в свой пост

Comment: @pavel  Добавил в свой код. До лампочки :(

Comment: @Harry да, оно больше помогает когда нужно и читать и писать. Странно что у вас `printf` работает насколько быстро. У меня разница в пределах погрешности (Ubuntu x64 g++).

Comment: @Harry мне кажется тут что-то с методикой подсчёта у вас. у меня вывод `cout sync : 155445
cout async: 338267
stdout    : 1158
` без файла и `cout sync : 790
cout async: 738
stdout    : 801` в файл, что совсем не правдоподобно. Причём запуская на стандартном цикле `#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

 
 
int main()
{
 //iostream::sync_with_stdio(false);
        //cin.tie(0);
        for (int i=0;i<100000000;i++)
              printf("%d ",i);//cout << i <<" ";
}` результаты почти одинаковые. (причём что в файл что в консоль)...

Comment: @pavel Я привел код программы, описал среду. Ключи компиляции - `/O2 /Ot /EHsc /MT`. Что я еще могу сделать? :) Сколько помню Windows (я на нее переполз с eComStation), у нее всегда вывод на консоль был существенно медленнее вывода в файл, вечно приходится в программах с бешеным выводом просто или в файл перенаправлять, или окошко минимизировать...

Comment: @Harry windows да, консоль медленная. И да, win10 результат запуска `cout sync : 777007
cout async: 71779
stdout    : 1327760` разница колоссальная) вот и гадайте что быстрее.

Comment: @Harry, а вы поставьте тест `printf` не первым, а вторым. Будете несколько удивлены результатам.

Comment: @MonahTuk Поставил. В файл `cout sync : 11964
cout async: 11489
stdout    : 5447`, на консоль `cout sync : 3213270
cout async: 3172014
stdout    : 1141586` Я должен был удивиться, что по сути ничего не изменилось? :)

Comment: Факир был пьян и фокус не удался :) gcc 5.3, Mint 17.3, ваш тест, первый блок всегда самый быстрый получался.

Comment: Примерно так: http://pastebin.com/gxerpqhe, сам тест: http://pastebin.com/MGZu7n63.