# Сравнение эффективности потоков C++ и файлов C

Tags: c++, c, windows, visual-c++, консоль

Навеяно [вопросом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/519579/%D0%A6%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-std-i-o-streams-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B8) о том, что следует использовать - потоки или файловые функции, и что потоки обычно медленнее.

Набросал тестовую программу (код ниже), испытал на Open Watcom и Visual C++ 2015. Сравниваются результаты вывода в консольное окно и в файл функциями для работы с потоками и с файлами. Чтоб работало со старым Watcom, для замера использовал `clock()`, попутно выяснилось, что в OW рекомендованная в упомянутом вопросе функция `ios::sync_with_stdio()` без параметров и *obsolete*, так что для этого компилятора ее убрал.

Проверял под Windows 7 x64. Вопросов, собственно, два - а что делается у других компиляторов и операционных систем, и как, собственно, можно ускорить вывод - как консольный вообще, так и потоковый до уровня функций C. Есть ли какие-то варианты оптимизации? Чем обусловлен наблюдаемый разброс?

Вот код:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdio>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

clock_t bench(void(*func)())
{
    clock_t start = clock();
    func();
    clock_t stop = clock();
    return stop - start;
}

const int Count = 100000;

vector<double> dv;
vector<int>    iv;

FILE * outfile = 0;
ofstream * outstream = 0;

void printf_console()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < Count; ++i)
        printf("%d %lf ",iv[i],dv[i]);
}

void printf_file()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < Count; ++i)
        fprintf(outfile, "%d %lf ",iv[i],dv[i]);
}

void stream_console()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < Count; ++i)
        cout << iv[i] << " " << dv[i] << " ";
}

void stream_file()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < Count; ++i)
        *outstream << iv[i] << " " << dv[i] << " ";
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < Count; ++i)
    {
        dv.push_back(rand()/double(RAND_MAX));
        iv.push_back(rand());
    }

    outfile = fopen("test.dat","wt");
    outstream = new ofstream("test.stream");

    clock_t out_printf_console = bench(printf_console);
    clock_t out_printf_file    = bench(printf_file);
    clock_t out_cout_sync      = bench(stream_console);
    clock_t out_stream_file    = bench(stream_file);
    ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    clock_t out_cout_async     = bench(stream_console);
    ios::sync_with_stdio(true);
    clock_t out_cout_rsync     = bench(stream_console);


    cerr << "\n\n";
    cerr << "printf       console: " << setw(10) << out_printf_console << endl;
    cerr << "printf       file   : " << setw(10) << out_printf_file    << endl;
    cerr << "stream sync  console: " << setw(10) << out_cout_sync      << endl;
    cerr << "stream async console: " << setw(10) << out_cout_async     << endl;
    cerr << "stream rsync console: " << setw(10) << out_cout_rsync     << endl;
    cerr << "stream       file   : " << setw(10) << out_stream_file    << endl;

    delete outstream;
    fclose(outfile);
}
```

А вот результаты:

```
                    Open Watcom:    VC++ 2015:
printf       console:      16739         21806
printf       file   :         62            69
stream sync  console:      16723         87678
stream async console:      16754         86899
stream rsync console:      16692         87254
stream       file   :        141           150
```

P.S. Удивляет что в общем случае VC++ бьет Open Watcom, а здесь - капитально ему проигрывает, в особенности при потоковом выводе в консоль.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39374/discussion-on-question-by-harry----c---c).

Answer (score 4):

@Harry, если интересны другие результаты.

Windows 7 MinGW g++ 3.4.5

```
printf       console:       4.43
printf       file   :      0.081
stream sync  console:     18.262
stream async console:      1.093
stream rsync console:      1.176
stream       file   :      0.318
```

и в виртуалке VirtualBox на том же компе

```
Linux avp-ubu1 3.13.0-85-generic #129-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 17 20:50:15 UTC 
2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
g++.real (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) 4.8.4

printf       console:    0.11216
printf       file   :   0.072135
stream sync  console:   0.152673
stream async console:   0.141306
stream rsync console:   0.141552
stream       file   :   0.070493
```

кстати о нем:

```
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ grep CPU /proc/cpuinfo 
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2500 CPU @ 3.30GHz
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2500 CPU @ 3.30GHz
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2500 CPU @ 3.30GHz
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2500 CPU @ 3.30GHz
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$
```

Время в секундах, поскольку глядя на сырую разницу clocks я заподозрил, что значение CLOCKS_PER_SEC в этих системах разное, короче вывод делается так:

```
cerr << "printf       console: " << setw(10) << (out_printf_console  /  (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC) << endl;
```

(остальные аналогично).

P.S.
разброс значений времени при разных запусках (для интереса я запускал раз пять) наблюдается, но похоже не больше 10%.

Comment: Т.е. Linux в виртуалке бьёт Windows-хозяина?

Comment: @sercxjo, IMHO разница в том, что `clock()` разные (системы пользуются разными источниками, подсчитывая время, предоставленное процессу). Наверное в этой задаче надо брать реальное время из `gettimeofday()`

Comment: В Linux есть на выбор 8 разновидностей таймеров (man clock_gettime).  Может проще посмотреть все сразу.

Comment: @sercxjo, ну, если старые вещи Вам не по нраву, да еще и учитывая `POSIX.1-2008 marks gettimeofday() as obsolete, recommending the
       use of clock_gettime(2) instead` измеряйте с `CLOCK_REALTIME` (только в любом случае не забывайте, что измерение времени это одна из самых темных тем в ОС).

Answer (score 2):

Первое. С таким подходом к измерению времени можно намерять такие интересные вещи, как погоду на Марсе, или влажность пяток певицы Монеточки.

Современная многозадачная система может внезапно захотеть в фоновом режиме перекинуть пару-тройку страниц с диска в RAM - вот вам и разброс времени.

Современный CPU может решить, что ему скучно работать на одной частоте, и культурненько ее снизить. Или поднять.

Вон какое количество копий поломано об одно только [измерение времени](https://habrahabr.ru/company/intel/blog/82832/).

Попробуйте повторить тесты из [известной публикации](https://habrahabr.ru/post/246257/), тогда ценность будет выше.

Comment: Согласен, код с IO измерять с помощью `clock()` неправильно (по крайней мере в Linux clock реализован : `on  top  of
       clock_gettime(2) (using the CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID clock)`. Наверное самым правильным будет использовать реальное время из `gettimeofday()`

Answer (score 0):

Разброс, возможно, обусловлен реализацией библиотеки.
Конечно (ИМХО) более объективный результат - не одиночный вызов, а прогон серии.
В качестве эксперимента можно попробовать stl извне, типа `STLPORT` или `EASTL`.